# writing, reading and exploding txt file content

Tags: php, explode

I got a textarea and a submit button, once i write stuff into the textarea and press the button - it writes the textarea content into a txt file, i need help formatting that content using explode. 
Here is the code im using to write the textarea content into a txt file:

```
$tavalues = ($_POST['dname']); //dname is textarea field
$filename = "imones.txt";
$fp = fopen ($filename, "w");
if ($fp){
    fwrite($fp, $tavalues);
} 
fclose($fp);
```

As u can see it writes into imones.txt file. Now i want to read that file content, format it, and write formatted content into another file. I cant seem to get how to write multiple delimiters for explode.. 
*Here is an example of how i input data into textarea* (all messy with commas and stuff):

```
example.com  example.com
 example.com, example.com
example.com
```

*Here is how i want it to get formatted* (basically i want to remove the ',' , '\n', '\r'):

```
example.com
example.com
example.com
```

..(all links in one line without any spaces, note that links are different and not the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this. It's quick and dirty. For a better solution you **should** try a regular expression!

```
$input = "exampleA.com  exampleB.com
 exampleC.com, exampleD.com
exampleE.com";
$tmp = explode(" ", $input);
$str = "";
$filename = "imones.txt";
$fp = fopen ($filename, "w");
if ($fp){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++) {
      if ($tmp[$i] != "") {
          $tmp[$i] = str_replace(",", "", $tmp[$i]);
          $tmp[$i] = trim($tmp[$i]);
          $str .= $tmp[$i]."\n";
      }
    }
fwrite($fp, $str);
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: like the method above, it also gives 2x new lines after each value for some reason

Comment: 2x new lines after each value? I'm sorry but I don't get this on my box. Weird!

Comment: Same here. This example works. [Here it is in my test](http://vetrastudios.com/text.php).

Answer (score 0):

How about converting all exploding-chars into one and than explode by this?!

```
$expl = ';';
$content = file_get_contents('imones.txt');
$content = str_replace(',', $expl, $content);
$content = str_replace('\n', $expl, $content);
$content = str_replace('\r', $expl, $content);
$content = str_replace(' ', $expl, $content);
// ...

while (strpos($content, "$expl$expl") !== false) { // while $expl is found twice
    $content = str_replace("$expl$expl", $expl, $content); // remove this
}

$parts = explode($expl, $content);

// than join them
$formatted = implode("\n", $parts);
file_put_contents('somefile.txt', $formatted);
```

Comment: for some reason it writes each value with a space instead of a newline, heres what i mean - it writes like this (example.com example.com example.com), where i want it to write like this (example.com\n example.com\n example.com\n (each value from new line))

Comment: Linux or Windows? Linux newline is "\n", Windows newline is "\r\n". May be this is the reason why.

Comment: seems like "\r\n" did add a newline, but now there are 2 spaces between values, like this (example.com  \nexample.com)

Comment: Maybe you need to add 
`$content = str_replace(' ', $expl, $content);`

Comment: it removes the spaces but now it adds 2 newlines after each value

Comment: I've added 3 lines. They will remove all ';;'. May be this was the reason for empty lines. Imagine the following string:
'google.com, wikipedia.com,stackoverflow.com' this would be converted to:
'google.com;;wikipedia.com;stackoverflow.com' after that... the result would be: 'google.com\n\nwikipedia.com\nstackoverflow.com'...  The given snippet is solving this.

Answer (score -1):

Give PHP's [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) a try.